# context condition for field group multipage

Tags: theming, 7, forms

I have a node form configured with field group multi page, my node form is outputted as a block on the front page. I want to disable(hide) the rest of my front page blocks when the user is on the second step or the third step.
Can i achieve this with context ?

Comment: You will have to create a custom context condition for this case. Here is an example of a custom condition, it should help you on the way: http://dtek.net/blog/extending-drupals-context-module-custom-condition-based-field-value